# Как перебрать все возможные варианты пароля?

Tags: python

Вот код, но он брутит только знакомый мне пароль, как сделать так, чтобы он подбирал неизвестный мне пароль

```
import random

correctPassword = "6537"
wrongPasswords = []
password = ""
length = 4
chars = "1234567890"
run = True

while run:
password = ""

for i in range(length):
    password += random.choice(chars)

if password not in wrongPasswords:
    if password != correctPassword:
        print(password)
        wrongPasswords.append(password)
    else:
        run = False
        break

print(password + " is correct")
```

Comment: что значит известный и неизвестный?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров думаю - длина и входящие символы

Comment: Нужно знать какая реакция наступает при введении пароля и программно вводить , пока не найдёт , если , конечно , нет лимита ввода ...
Программе же ничего не стоит это ( вводить данные ) ...
И , если знать реакцию - цикл перебора написать - даже в радость ...

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
# File     : 1093133.py
# Modified : <2020-3-22 Sun 16:38:54 GMT>
# URL      : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098155

import string
import itertools
import time


password_real = "6537"
start_time = time.time()

guess_password_set = string.digits + string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
guess_password_length = 1


def string_iter(string, length):
    yield from itertools.product(*([string] * length))


while True:
    for password_set in string_iter(guess_password_set, guess_password_length):
        password_string = ''.join(password_set)
        if password_string == password_real:
            end_time = time.time()
            exec_time = end_time - start_time
            print("Password is found for {}s: {}"
                  .format(exec_time, password_string))
            exit()
    guess_password_length += 1
```

```
$ python3 1098155.py
Password is found for 1.808835744857788s: 6537
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас опробую

Comment: нет, это не то. мне надо чтобы программа подбирала пароль и вводила его в строку с паролем, чтобы так методом подбора я узнал пароль. например: у моего друга есть пк и на нем есть запароленный файл. мне надо узнать пароль от файла, и чтобы с этой задачей автоматически справилась программа.

Comment: @Dikon в вопросе этого нет

Comment: ну да, это мой косяк уже

Comment: `itertools.product(*([string] * length))` - зачем так сложно? `itertools.product(string, repeat=length)`.